# Getting an error while integrating Razorpay in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

while integrating Razorpay in iOS swift getting an error

> module compiled with swift 4.1 cannot be imported by the swift 5.6.1
> compiler: /users/ravindra/documents/sample
> projects/ruby/pods/razorpay-pod/pod/razorpay.framework/modules/razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

I am using swift 5 with Xcode 13.4 through the pod file. Please provide a detailed tutorial for iOS  app integration.

Comment: the version of razorpay you are using was compiled with an older version of swift, you need to use a newer version. Update the version of razorpay you are using

Comment: Also, `Please provide a detailed tutorial...` is not what StackOverflow is about.